How to fix the contents of php.ini (version 8.2) file or generate a new one
I am trying to run the data base connectivity program related to PHP on Ubuntu 22.04:
<?php
include('dbconnection.php');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";


echo "Testing";
//https://forum.infinityfree.com/t/cant-connect-my-php-to-mysql/63505/15#google_vignette
$mysqli = @new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'does_not_exist');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    /* Use your preferred error logging method here */
    echo "Error Testing";
    error_log('Connection error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
}
else {

echo "No error";
}
?>

It gives me the output "Testing".I checked the php.ini but I found that it does not have the line:
;extension=php_mysqli.dll

The php.ini file contents are at: https://github.com/zulfi100/files
Somebody please check my php.ini file and let me know if its correct. If not kindly guide me how to correct it.
Zulfi.

The ini file is showing mysqli is enabled already, try and run php -r 'if (extension_loaded("mysqli")) {echo "yes";}'. If it outputs yes, then the problem is with your script. Otherwise, install the php-mysql package: sudo apt install php-mysql
